# hive delete partition mismatch one day

Tags: hadoop, hive

here is my table

```
hive> show create table pv;
OK
CREATE TABLE `pv`(
  `pv` int)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `d` date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://hadoop1:8020/user/hive/warehouse/pv'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1510813098')
Time taken: 0.135 seconds, Fetched: 14 row(s)
```

insert one record to test

```
hive> insert into table pv  partition(d="2017-11-16") values (10);
..
..


hive> select * from pv;
OK
10      2017-11-16
Time taken: 0.228 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from pv where d = "2017-11-16";
OK
10      2017-11-16
Time taken: 0.242 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

**the quesion is when i try to drop partition '2017-11-16', but the data belong to this partition still exist, unless i drop partition '2017-11-17', then the data i just insert is gone, but it should belong to partion '2017-11-16'..**

```
hive> ALTER TABLE pv DROP PARTITION (d='2017-11-16');
OK
Time taken: 0.124 seconds
hive> select * from pv;
OK
10      2017-11-16
Time taken: 0.212 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> ALTER TABLE pv DROP PARTITION (d='2017-11-18');
OK
Time taken: 0.118 seconds
hive> select * from pv;
OK
10      2017-11-16
Time taken: 0.208 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> ALTER TABLE pv DROP PARTITION (d='2017-11-17');
Dropped the partition d=2017-11-16
OK
Time taken: 0.312 seconds
hive> select * from pv;
OK
Time taken: 0.162 seconds
hive>
```

Comment: Run an `MSCK REPAIR` on the table after dropping partitions. Also, Hive CLI is deprecated

Comment: i think it 's not relate to msck repaire, when i drop partion d('2017-11-16'), i can see the dir /user/hive/warehouse/pv/d=2017-11-16 still exist, but when i drop partion d("2017-11-17"), the dir user/hive/warehouse/pv/d=2017-11-16 was deleted, i have drop the table, and redo it for a few time to test it. But i try to use beeline client, i work as expected!